# How to stop Sidekiq from clearing all queues when starting

Tags: sidekiq

When I start a sidekiq process, it seems to delete all queued jobs. I can verify this with the Sidekiq web UI. When a process starts, the enqueued tab always resets to 0, and the number in the processed tab doesn't change. I can also see the job data being removed from redis. Is this expected? Seems like it makes it impossible to restart workers without losing all scheduled jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My app was calling `Rails.cache.clear` on startup, which actually calls Redis' flush method, clearing the entire db:

https://github.com/redis-store/redis-store/issues/82

In my case the solution was to simply stop calling `Redis.cache.clear` on startup (or ever for that matter), but I could have also used a separate redis db for my sidekiq jobs.